# Should I use a nested class to encapsulate map values?

Tags: java, c++, dictionary, nested-class

I have a class with a map (e.g. hashmap). The map values contain different elements which could have different types. My question is whether is better to implement if using different map with the same Keys; or using a nested class for encapsulate all the elements.

Pseudo-code example with nested class.

```
public class MyMap<T> {
    private class Element{
          int nElementA;
          int nElementB;
          double dbElementC;
    }

    private Map<T,Element> map = new HashMap<T,Element>();

    public int getElementA(T key) {return map.get(key).nElementA;}
    public int getElementB(T key) {return map.get(key).nElementB;}
    public double getElementC(T key) {return map.get(key).nElementC;}
}
```

Pseudo-code example with multiple maps.

```
public class MyMap<T> {
    private Map<T,Integer> mapA = new HashMap<T,Integer>();
    private Map<T,Integer> mapB = new HashMap<T,Integer>();
    private Map<T,Double> mapC = new HashMap<T,Double>();

    public int getElementA(T key) {return mapA.get(key);}
    public int getElementB(T key) {return mapB.get(key);}
    public double getElementC(T key) {return mapC.get(key);}
}
```

I think that nested class (especially private ones) can have negative effect on future code maintenance. However, I feel that I am wasting resources if I am using multiple maps with the same keys. Do I have any other alternative to reuse the map keys?

I was coding in Java when the problem arises, but I am also interesting in solutions for C++.

Comment: is it possible to create an Element without filling all inner-elements?

Comment: Are elements A,B,C properties of the same object?

Comment: @APT , My original idea considers it. I guess, that by default, values could be initialized to `null` or `NAN`.

Comment: @bigGuy , In the original question, A,B,C are not properties of the same Object, otherwise we could use this object for the values of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is not **getting** the elements but **putting** them.
If the elements are related to each other, for instance `Name`, `Age` and `Sex`, encapsulating is better.

However, if they are tottaly different - which I think is not - you may use different maps.

My advice would be to make the class not private.
A single line

```
map.put(Integer, new Element("John", 51, "Male"));
```

is better than

```
map1.put(Integer, "John");
map2.put(Integer, 51);
map3.put(Integer, "Male");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a design decision, use the nested class solution only if make sense that the three elements can be encapsulate together under a single class. Take in account "high cohesion" when design your classes